# Creating mock API using MockWebServer and calling by WebTestClient using spring boot 3 giving 404 error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mocking, spring-boot-test

I am working on a  project to upgrade it to springboot 3.Now i am facing 404 NOT_FOUND error in junit test while mocking API using MockWebServer and WebTestClient.I am using 4.10.0 version of okhttp
testImplementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.10.0")
testImplementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0")

My code snippet :

```
    @LocalServerPort
    private int port = 0;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() throws IOException {
        mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();
        mockWebServer.start(8034);
        baseUri = "http://localhost:" + port;
        this.webClient = WebTestClient.bindToServer().responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10)).baseUrl(baseUri).build();
    }



    @WithMockUser(authorities = "csn")   
    @Test
    public void contextLoadsWithRoutedRequestOk() {
        mockWebServer.enqueue(new MockResponse().setResponseCode(200));
   webClient.get().uri("/test").exchange().expectStatus().isOk();
}
```